# How to set multiple conditions in python

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to specify two conditions in selecting my data. This is my code

```
data = np.genfromtxt("ca1_data/mrtfares.csv",
               delimiter=',',skip_header=1,
               dtype=[('Fare_Type','U50'),('Applicable_Time','U50'),('Distance','U50'),('Fare_per_Ride','i8')],
               missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values=[0])

x_adultcard = data[data['Fare_Type']=='Single trip' and data['Applicable_Time']=='All timings']['Distance']
y_adultcard = data[data['Fare_Type']=='Single trip' and data['Applicable_Time']=='All timings']['Fare_per_Ride']
```

But i am getting this error

```
---> 14 x_adultcard = data[data['Fare_Type']=='Single trip' and data['Applicable_Time']=='All timings']['Distance']
     15 y_adultcard = data[data['Fare_Type']=='Single trip' and data['Applicable_Time']=='All timings']['Fare_per_Ride']
     16 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This might be a very obvious answer? I am just starting to learn python so i do not know much. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't pure python, this is _numpy_. Comparisons will perhaps not work as you expect if you're not used to array programming. `x_adultcard = data[(data['Fare_Type']=='Single trip') & (data['Applicable_Time']=='All timings')]['Distance']` may work

Comment: Hi this does work. Can you put it as an answer so i can upvote and mark it as correct?

Comment: I think you'll probably want to look into `pandas` for this rather than numpy. It was designed for this kind of data rather than numpy

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @roganjosh! I will look into it however as this is a school assignment, sadly, I am not allowed to use pandas. I will learn it for future use though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for numpy arrays use `&` as and, `|` as or

Comment: This is not enough (not just in terms of solving the issue, but actually in way of any kind of explanation). I've also just noticed that they're creating structured arrays

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it works but I have to put the condition in () bracket. Thanks man!